# Cannot trigger on change for input type='file' from a Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, text-files, filereader

I am trying to load a text file from a Firefox Addon, but I cannot trigger on change even in order to read the selected file.

popup.html contains

```
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

loadFile.js contains

```
$('#file').change(function () {
  var $i = $('#file');
  var input = $i[0];
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      file = input.files[0];
      fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = function () {
          console.log("happening")
      };
      fr.readAsText( file );
  } else {
      alert("File not selected or browser incompatible.")
  }
});
```

Is this something related to being a popup or Addon? Please, I really need help. I have tried so many different things that didn't work at all, this one opens the dialog form but I cannot get the on change to trigger.